# Setting row height in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to programatically set the height of rows in a ListView based off of some scaling factor. I've been looking around the internet for hours and cannot figure out why my code doesn't work.

**UPDATE**
Actually more things with the layout are having problems than just the height. The layout_weight in the XML file for all the TextViews doesn't do anything at all. Setting the textSize on the TextViews programatically doesn't work either, the text is bigger than I set it. But setting visibility on the TextViews works perfectly fine as well as setting the text. Another thing to mention is that the only thing I can think of that separates this from any normal situation in which this code would work is that I'm putting this ListView in a custom ViewGroup.

Here's my adapter code for getView() where I'm trying to set the height.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View layout = convertView;

    if (layout == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_parameter, parent, false);
    }

    int rowHeight = (int) (defaultRowHeight * scale);

    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, rowHeight));
    layout.requestLayout();


    Parameter p = getItem(position);
    TextView tvName = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvValue = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvValue);
    TextView tvMin = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvMin);
    TextView tvMax = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvMax);
    TextView tvAvg = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvAvg);

    if (showName) {
        tvName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvName.setTextSize(defaultTextSize * scale);
        tvName.setText(p.getName());
    } else {
        tvName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (showValue) {
        tvValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvValue.setTextSize(defaultTextSize * scale);
        tvValue.setText(formatValue(p.getCurrentValue().value, p));
    } else {
        tvValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (showMin) {
        tvMin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvMin.setTextSize(defaultTextSize * scale);
        tvMin.setText(formatValue(p.getMinValue().value, p));
    } else {
        tvMin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (showMax) {
        tvMax.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvMax.setTextSize(defaultTextSize * scale);
        tvMax.setText(formatValue(p.getMaxValue().value, p));
    } else {
        tvMax.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (showAvg) {
        tvAvg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvAvg.setTextSize(defaultTextSize * scale);
        tvAvg.setText(formatValue(p.getAverage(), p));
    } else {
        tvAvg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return layout;
}
```

And here's my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <!-- More TextViews here -->
```

The rows all show up just fine with the expected content, but the height isn't correct.

Comment: What do you mean by the height isn't correct?

Comment: How are you passing the scale to this?

Comment: I've logged what `rowHeight` is just before setting it and it should be 66 but the actual height ends up being 48. The scale is stored in the adapter.

Comment: I updated the question with some more relevant information.